# Show an alert on UI

Tags: android

I am running the following in my `LaunchActivity` `onCreate()`

```
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            OneSignal.init(LaunchActivity.this, AppGlobal.GCMProjectNumber, AppGlobal.OneSignalAppID, new OneSignalNotificationOpened(LaunchActivity.this));
            Log.d("OneSignal", "Initialized");
            oneSignalInitialized = true;
        }
    });
```

Here is my `OneSignalNotificationOpened` class:

```
class OneSignalNotificationOpened implements NotificationOpenedHandler {
    Context context;

    public OneSignalNotificationOpened(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public void notificationOpened(String message, JSONObject additionalData, boolean isActive) {
        String messageTitle = "OneSignal Example", messageBody = message;
        String tag = "launch";

        try {
                if (additionalData.has("title")){
                    messageTitle = additionalData.getString("title");
                }
                if (additionalData.has("actionSelected")){
                    messageBody += "\nPressed ButtonID: " + additionalData.getString("actionSelected");
                }


                messageBody = message;
            if(additionalData.has("bookId")){
                bookIndex = Integer.parseInt(additionalData.getString("bookId"));
                if(bookIndex >= 0){
                    restrictBookListActivity = true;

                    if(AppPreferences.ShopBookList != null) {
                        Book theBook = AppPreferences.ShopBookList.get(bookIndex);
                        Log.i(tag, "stored: " + theBook.getName());
                        Bundle data = new Bundle();
                        data.putSerializable("param1", theBook);

                        //notificationReceived(messageTitle, messageBody, bookIndex);
                        final Intent detailActivity = new Intent(LaunchActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                        detailActivity.putExtras(data);
//                        startActivity(detailActivity);

                        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        dialog.setTitle("Notification received!");
                        dialog.setMessage("This is body");
                        dialog.setCancelable(true);
                        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                startActivity(detailActivity);
                            }
                        });
                        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        });
                        dialog.show();


                        //startActivity(detailActivity);
                    }else Log.i(tag, "book list is null");
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Error", "Error: " + e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

I open another activity using `Handler().postDelayed()` in `onCreate()` to go to another activity. When I receive notification I am in that activity. `dialog.show()` in `OneSignalNotificationOpened` throws `WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window`. How can I solve this?

**Update**: I checked is my activity get finished before showing the dialog by `isFinishing()` and found that it gets finished. So how can I show the alert?

Comment: Try checking if your activity isFinishing() before showing the dialog, if so you can't show it.

Comment: Ok. All of my activities are extending `BaseActivity`. I tried to call a method from BaseActivity to show this alert. But same thing happens there also. My BaseActivity never gets finished am I right? Should the same be happened for BaseActivity?

Comment: @CoolBrain No you are not right - if you extend something it means that you just having base object in your class (think about that like that). It has nothing to do with android life cycle.

Comment: Then can you suggest anything ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to show a dialog with the message contents when a notification is received while the user is using your app you can simply call `OneSignal.enableInAppAlertNotification(true);` after `OneSignal.init(...);`. Or if you always want the notification to go to the notification area you can call `OneSignal.enableNotificationsWhenActive(true);` instead.

See the [OneSignal Android API Reference](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-api) page for more details on the above methods.

If you need a more customized alert dialog you can add a static Activity variable to your `BaseActivity` class that each of your Activity classes extent. Set this static variable in the [onResume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) method in your `BaseActivity` and use it as the context for `new AlertDialog.Builder(context);`